# AsyncTask not working correctly when executed from within an setOnClickListener

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to log into a web server and I had the code running correctly but when I tried to build a log in page around it things started to go wrong.

I was using the example Log in page provided in the Eclipse Android tools if anyone wants to see any of the extra bits of code.

If I execute from within the OnClickHandler then the DefaultHttpClient just seems to time out. It doesn't return anything or if it does it returns "No peer certificate" which I know is wrong.

```
/**
 * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
 */
private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;
```

... Set up stuff

```
    mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask();
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(attemptLogin()){
                        mAuthTask.execute();
                    }
                }
            });
    //mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(); 
    //mAuthTask.execute();  // Works if called from here.
```

Here's the relevent AsyncTask code:

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG,"Thread name (from preexecute) : " +  Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        DefaultHttpClient client = AppHttpClient.getClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://euw.leagueoflegends.com/user/login");
        String result = "";
        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "exampleusername"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "blahblah"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("form_id", "user_login"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            Log.i(TAG,"Thread name (passed into doInBackground) : " +  urls[0]);
            Log.i(TAG,"Thread name (from doInBackground) : " +  Thread.currentThread().getName());
            HttpResponse response2 = client.execute(httppost);
            InputStream in = response2.getEntity().getContent();
            //result = readStream(in);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the complete code of your AsyncTask?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301565/1489493) from a Google Engineer:

> AsyncTask's pre and postExecute methods are invoked on the thread on
>   which the task instance was created. Where you call execute() doesn't
>   matter. The thread on which you create the task must be a looper
>   thread and in practice should always be the main thread (or UI
>   thread.)

**Edit:**

You should try this code (not tested):

```
private mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask();
findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(attemptLogin()){
                    Activity.this.runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mAuthTask.execute();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: That exact code causes this error: "No enclosing instance of the type Activity is accessible in scope". I tried removing the `Activity.this.` but the HttpClient continues to freeze, or get stuck in a loop or get dereferenced or something. Thanks for your help though.