# MultiThreading AsyncTask with a listener

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I created AsyncTask on Thread1 and a listener object on the MainThread. I am aware that the method onPostExecute returns to the thread on which the asyncTask was created. My question is whether it is possible to call the listener object in onPostExecute and suddenly be running on the MainThread again (since that is the thread on which the object was created)?

I ask this because AsyncTask returns to the thread of creation - [Android : can AsyncTask return in another thread than UI thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300897/android-can-asynctask-return-in-another-thread-than-ui-thread)

Could the same apply to a listener object as I've described above?

Comment: If you are creating asynctask on the Main UI Thread then why do you need the listener? onPostExecute method will be running in UI Thread.

Comment: From your link: "The thread on which you create the task must be a looper thread and **in practice should always be the main thread (or UI thread.)**"

Comment: In practice. I'm asking if it is possible this occurs because I have an assumption it has happened in my code. If i were writing from zero I would obviously make sure recommmeneded practices are being used but that is not the case right now.